# when read buffer size is 2048, it work , but buffer size is 48 or other number, write call will be blocked, why?

Tags: fifo, select

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){ 
        puts("err argv");
        return -1; 
    }   

    int r_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    int w_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    fd_set r_set;
    fd_set w_set;
    char w_buf[4096];
    char r_buf[2048];
    int read_count = 0,write_count = 0;  
    while(1){
        FD_ZERO(&r_set);
        FD_ZERO(&w_set);
        FD_SET(r_fd, &r_set);
        FD_SET(w_fd, &w_set);
        int ret = select(w_fd + 1, &r_set, &w_set, NULL, NULL);
        if(FD_ISSET(r_fd, &r_set)){
            read(r_fd, r_buf, sizeof(r_buf));    
            printf("read count:%d\n", read_count++);    
        }   
        if(FD_ISSET(w_fd, &w_set)){
            write(w_fd, w_buf, sizeof(w_buf));
            printf("write count:%d\n", write_count++);  
        }   
        //sleep(1);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

execute code：mkfifo 1.fifo && gcc main.c -o main && ./main 1.fifo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You mean it works the way it is here, with `char r_buf[2048];`, but changing it to `char r_buf[48];` or so makes it fail? Or something else?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, change 2048 to 48, write call will be blocked

Comment: @zhenfeiren, right, I forgot to ask, what system did you test this on? It may affect the exact behaviour, e.g. I can't get that to lock on Linux, but can if I increase the write size. It looks to me like it always writes a full page of 4096 bytes, so the write never blocks.

Comment: @ilkkachu I test this on macOS .The maximum write buffer size is 4096 ,so you increase it will block

Comment: I later changed the main.c to read and write files, the flag of the open function of the write.c file was changed to O_RDONLY, and the flag of the open function of the read.c file was changed to O_WRONLY. At this time, even if the read buffer size is 48 , it will not block anymore

Comment: You mean `select` behaves differently depending on the fd mode, and not just whether it is in the read or write fd set? That seems unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(FD_ISSET(w_fd, &w_set)){
            write(w_fd, w_buf, sizeof(w_buf));
            printf("write count:%d\n", write_count++);  
        }
```

If `select` tells you an fd is writable, that means you can write *at least one byte*. The threshold may be higher than 1, depending on how the FIFO buffer is managed, but it certainly doesn't mean you can write 4096 bytes without blocking.

This code is statically wrong and must set both fds to non-blocking mode (and be ready to handle `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` return codes appropriately) to be reasonably robust.

The *reason* some read buffer sizes expose the problem is to do with whether you can reach a situation where the FIFO is empty enough that `w_fd` shows as writeable, but too full for the write to complete (so it blocks).

You could trivially confirm or falsify this by attaching a debugger to the blocked process, or running it under strace. These are both perfectly normal tools you should learn to use.

Comment: _"but it certainly doesn't mean you can write 4096 bytes without blocking"_ -- as far as I tested on Linux, in practice it seemed to mean just that. :) You're right though, if it works it's something of an accident.

Comment: But I'm not sure how changing the read buffer size matters, even if we always read just one byte less than the corresponding write, the buffers should creep slowly fuller, until the next write doesn't fit in. Unless it's not just about the numbers but also alignment or something.

Comment: If you can end up with say 3Kb free in the buffer, _and_ the select marks the fd writable, _then_ you will do a blocking write of 4Kb and block forever. So the only question is which read size gets you into that situation. Anyway, why are we speculating when it's trivial for OP to confirm where their code blocked?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in checking both r_set and w_set after a single select -- possibly a race condition where the read or write invalidates the result.

This is a robust version, with extra debug, and some results.

It is important to do any available reads before writes. If you give the writes precedence, it will fill the fifo (probably up to 64KB) before the reads get a look-in. This may be part of the race condition in your original code.

```
//  xSelect.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        puts("err argv");
        return -1;
    }
    ssize_t r_res, w_res;
    int r_fd, w_fd;
    r_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    w_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR); 
    fprintf (stderr, "r_fd %d, w_fd %d\n", r_fd, w_fd);

    fd_set r_set;
    fd_set w_set;
    char w_buf[4096];
    char r_buf[1235];

    for (int j = 0, w = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        FD_ZERO(&r_set);
        FD_ZERO(&w_set);
        FD_SET(r_fd, &r_set);
        FD_SET(w_fd, &w_set);
        int ret = select(w_fd + 1, &r_set, &w_set, NULL, NULL);
        if(FD_ISSET(r_fd, &r_set)){
            r_res = read(r_fd, r_buf, sizeof(r_buf));
            fprintf (stderr, "Read %zd\n", r_res);
        } else if(w++ < 3 && FD_ISSET(w_fd, &w_set)){
            w_res = write(w_fd, w_buf, sizeof(w_buf));
            fprintf (stderr, "Write %zd\n", w_res);
        } else {
            fprintf (stderr, "Tick\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ make xSelect && echo Run && ./xSelect xSelect.fifo
cc xSelect.c -o xSelect
Run
r_fd 3, w_fd 4
Write 4096
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 391
Write 4096
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 391
Write 4096
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 1235
Read 391
Tick
Tick
Tick
Tick
Tick
$
```

EDIT: I may have over-thought this. I do not think the r_set and w_set are directly affected by a single read and/or write: they are however obsoleted by those actions.

In your original code, `w_fd` will always be writeable until the FIFO is completely full. So if you do equal numbers of long writes and short reads, the writer will eventually hang. If your short reads are 2048 bytes, then you will need about 32 cycles to fill the fifo: if short reads are 48, you will fill the fifo with 17 cycles.

Obviously, the average rates of writing and reading must be equal in the long-term. Typically, the kernel achieves this by not scheduling the writer (which is in a different process), but your code enforces one read, one-write. So the `w_set.w_fd` eventually becomes unset.

One problem is that the select() does not know how much data you plan to write. If the fifo has space for one byte, w_fd is writeable. I do not know whether the write is truncated, or blocked, or failed, and whether having both fds using the same fifo makes any difference. It is not even worth testing, because the answer may depend on the OS, and whether we are using a fifo or a socket, or some other factor. Your code should be written to deal with a partial write, an error returning EAGAIN, ***and*** blocking.

Your code suffers from completely filling the fifo, and mine from completely emptying the fifo unnecessarily after each write. A proper demo should tune (or randomise) its behaviour to explore the possibilities.

Comment: I'd also put the fd's in non-blocking mode anyway, just in case. Not that it seems to be a problem the way you do it here, emptying the pipe each time before writing more. Unless you ever try to write more than can go there in one go...

Comment: @ilkkachu  Of course, very true (and I missed it). If the write is allowed to block, the read is never reached, and we are in deadlock.